# Convert MainApp from an MFC application into a secondary dialog

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

Hello fellow programmers, I come back to you to ask for a quick way to do something with MFC applications.

I have two MFC applications, and I want one to launch the other in a separate thread, so I can have both services running from executing a single *exe* file.

I'm actually new to MFC so I don't actually know what options I do have. Tried some dirty things but I keep getting duplicated resources problem, not to mention both apps start with `BOOL CMainApp::InitInstance()` and I'm guessing there is no way to have two initialization instances.

That being said, is there any quick way to rewrite one of the apps to become a secondary dialog without causing too much headache?

Thank you in advance, and excuse me if I'm asking something weird or easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what kind of MFC applications are they? MDI, SDI, Dialog-based?

Here are some options:

1. If the secondary app is Dialog-based, the conversion is pretty simple: you need to move implementation files for that dialog into the first app and merge the resources.
2. If both applications are MDI - you can merge their Document Templates so that the first app will be able to operate on all document/view types.
3. Otherwise - did you consider simply spawning the second app via `CreateProcess()`? What is the significance of them being run from "a single exe file"?

Comment: Thank you for the response Vlad Feinstein, I suppose its dialog based. I tried moving the implementation files as well as the resources, but I keep getting duplicate resource problem. And both apps are started with an initInstance, I think it doesnt actually know which one to start as main app. I'll keep this aside as I still have to do many coding in the main app and I'll try it as soon as I have a fully functional code. On the other hand, how does CreateProcess() work? I guess it starts a separate executable from within an app? Thank you again.

Comment: Alright, I'm done with the code and I already implemented the CreateProcess() call, it really works like a charm!! Thank you so much for the hints Vlad.